# Number of bytes allocated with malloc call in C

Tags: c, malloc, byte

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXROW 3
#define MAXCOL 23
int main(){
    int (*p)[MAXCOL];
    p = (int (*) [MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW *sizeof(*p));
    return 0;
}
```

I need to know how many bytes will be allocated for the following code (for this p).
also, is the casting before the malloc adds/frees bytes that were allocated in the malloc if the size is different ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is dedicated to many programming languages. Please add an appropriate tag to your questions to get relevant answers.

Comment: `printf("%zu", (MAXROW *sizeof(*p)))`

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a pointer to an array of `int` of length `MAXCOL`. And so `sizeof(*p)` is the size of an array of `int` of length `MAXCOL`. Hence `MAXROW *sizeof(*p)` is equal to `MAXROW*MAXCOL*sizeof(int)`.

Casting of the return value of `malloc` is not needed since `malloc` returns `void*`. As a general rule, in C code, you should not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: it's `sizeof(*p)`, not `sizeof(p)`

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(*p)` is the size of an array of `MAXCOL` `int`s, or `MAXCOL * sizeof(int)`.

So, the `malloc` call you present will allocate `MAXROW * MAXCOL * sizeof(int)` bytes.

About the cast : it will not impact how many bytes are allocated by the `malloc` call. In fact, it's completely unnecessary (and in this case without any effect), and is better left out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your architecture, if ints are 32 or 64 bits. Then as David says, is MAXROW times that size.